# React will animate every time if I use function componment

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am rendering svg polyline,

```
const SVG = () => {
  const svgRef = React.createRef<SVGSVGElement>();
  const [tooltipIndex, setTooltipIndex] = React.useState(-1);
  const onTouch = (e: React.TouchEvent) => {
    setTooltipIndex(tooltipIndex + 1);
  };

  const PolyLine = () => {
    return <polyline className="ctLine" points="200,100 100,150 200,250" />;
  };
  return (
    <svg
      width="200"
      height="300"
      viewBox="0 0 200 300"
      ref={svgRef}
      onTouchStart={(e) => onTouch(e)}
    >
      <polyline className="ctLine" points="100,50 60,90 30,60" />;
      <PolyLine />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

the class is like this:

```
.ctLine {
  stroke: #0074d9;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  animation-name: ctLineShow;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes ctLineShow {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 1000; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}
```

Source are here https://codepen.io/rogerdehe/pen/dyYEVoQ

I find that function componment `PolyLine` diff from `polyline`:
`PolyLine` will animate every time when state change while `polyline` will not?

My question is:

1. Why
2. can I fix `PolyLine` to make it just like `polyline`?

Comment: Can you try making `Polyline` a pure functional component using `React.memo()`

Answer (score 1):

First - you are right. React component will render on props/state change - it's expected behavior.

Second -  you placed your `PolyLine` component inside `SVG`. When you call `setTooltipIndex` on `onTouchStart` it creates new context on each render. Move `PolyLine` out of `SVG` to prevent unnecessary rendering.

```
 const PolyLine = () => {
    console.log('render');
    return <polyline className="ctLine" points="200,100 100,150 200,250" />;
  };

const SVG = () => {
  const svgRef = React.createRef<SVGSVGElement>();
  const [tooltipIndex, setTooltipIndex] = React.useState(-1);
  const onTouch = (e: React.TouchEvent) => {
    setTooltipIndex(tooltipIndex + 1);
....
```